# MySQL select need count if field less than 0 and greater than 0

Tags: php, mysql

Is there a way to write a mysql select statement to run a count for a particular 1 field only, if greater than zero and equal to zero.

I could write 2 statements to achieve this but is it possible to do it in a single statement.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Something like this perhaps:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN x > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as GreatherThanZero
    , SUM(CASE WHEN x = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as EqualZero
FROM table
WHERE x >= 0
```

Comment: what if we want only distinct x?

Answer (score 5):

Yes.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Table WHERE Field > 0
UNION SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Table WHERE Field = 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN column > 0 THEN column ELSE 0 END CASE), SUM(CASE WHEN column < 0 THEN column ELSE 0 END CASE) FROM mytable
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, if I understood your question correctly, something like this should work:

```
SELECT
   COUNT(Field)
FROM
   Table
WHERE 
   Field >= 0
```